# How to pass AWS credentials to Kubernetes Javascript client?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-java-client

I have inherited some Javascript code that creates a client and then does a namespace query on an EKS cluster:

```
   //Get API client for k8s
    let k8sApplicationAPI = this.kubeConfig.makeApiClient(k8s.AppsV1Api);
    //Get deployments
    k8sApplicationAPI.listNamespacedDeployment(namespaceName)
```

How do I pass the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to the client?

Or, more accurately, how do I pass these needed environment variables to the client?

Comment: I assume it would work if the host that you are running the code has a kubeconfig and you use `const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig(); kc.loadFromDefault();` kubernetes clients have no knowledge of aws credentials

Comment: @Furkan Ok.  Put another way, how would I pass these as environment variables?

Comment: to the client? you can't. For the node application `process.env.ENV_NAME`

Comment: @Furkan so, you're saying that there is no way to pass env var data to the client, but you *can* to the node application using the client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the aws credential file probably. It exists here ~/.aws/credentials

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

This will run you through a cli wizard and it creates that file which gets used by the client.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. :) I need to pass those values *inside* the api.  I cannot rely on them being set in the shell environment.